# Deal with data as DataTable to Observable Collection in xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I would like to take advice from your side. As you know mostly in xamarin forms`enter code here` using `mvvm` pattern in the `view models`, people used to use most of the time `ObservableCollection` to hold items. I have old `windows forms application` and some `class libraries` when i have methods which get data as `DataTable`. I already migrated all class libraries from `.NET framework` to `.Net Standard` to be able to share logic also in `Xamarin`, nevertheless i wonder how i can deal when getting data for instance `DataTable GetAllPeple()`. Should i just somehow convert `DataTable` placed in my `repository class` data to `ObseravbleCollection` placed in ViewModel? Can anyone give me a hint how this could be done. Also vice versa when want to update some records. 
Hope you got my point. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the MVVM or similar pattern, you should handle the GetAllPeople data in the ViewModel only, and put it into the Model (to the ObservableCollection) along with other model data the View needs. If you can access the DataTable as a collection and get rows and columns, create a class with needed properties (and INotifyPropertyChanged) turn the rows and columns into properties in the class and add to the ObservableCollection.

Comment: so i could make reference to my repository (which have GetAll as DataTable) in ViewModel class - then the ViewModel class will be the place where i coul make conversion from DataTable to Model items and then to Observable?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can see, that is a proper MVVM wat of doing these things. Let the ViewModel (or service) handle the dirty work and keep the View and Model clean and neat :-)